# Using p5.js, node.js and mongodb for a complete website

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, p5.js

I want to create a small mini-mart website using all the javascript codes, p5.js for frontend, node.js for backend and mongodb for the database.
Is it good to work with all the javascript codes?
if not, what are other js to work on?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it, although P5 is not that great for frontend... Node.js is good, but unless you just want to build an HTTP server from scratch with the default node.js API you should use something like Express. Also, you should use something like Mongoose for interaction with the Mongo database, since it usually makes everything much easier!